# Specify the Source of dynamically created image c#

Tags: c#, wpf

First, I create the image:

```
var Image = new Image()
{
    Name = "AvatarOf_" + User.ID
    /* etc */
};

UserGrid.Children.Add(Image);
AppContent.Children.Add(UserGrid);
```

After the image is loaded from the Web and saved in the folder of a cache, I need to set an image source:

```
Image Object = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(("AvatarOf_" + User.ID)) as Image;
Object.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + Path));
```

As a result I receive an error because `Object` isn't recognized.
What's wrong?

Comment: So is your error actually occurring at the point you attempt to access your resources?  Or at the point when you attempt to set the Source property?

Comment: Naming a UI element doesn't make it a resource, hence you can't retrieve it from ResourceManager. Try `FindName()` instead. Or better just keep a reference to the dynamically created Image control in a member variable in your (Window?) class.

Comment: Or find it by `var image = AppContent.Children.OfType<Image>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AvatarOf_" + User.ID);`

Comment: @Clemens @Daniel Shillcock `System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`. It can be because Image in UserGrid which in AppContent?

Comment: Like has been mentioned above, you haven't actually added the image to application/ grid resources, thus when you search for the resource there's no match, Object remains null, and then you try to access a property on a null value which throws the error